# About number of threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I am reading concurrency programming guide in ios dev site

when move to the section "Moving away from thread" ,Apple said

> Although threads have been around for many years and continue to have
>   their uses, they do not solve the general problem of executing
>   multiple tasks in a scalable way. With threads, the burden of creating
>   a scalable solution rests squarely on the shoulders of you, the
>   developer. **You have to decide how many threads to create and adjust
>   that number dynamically as system conditions change**. Another problem
>   is that your application assumes most of the costs associated with
>   creating and maintaining any threads it uses.

follow my previous learning,the OS will take care about process-thread management , and programmer just only create and destroy threads in desire ,

is it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not wrong.  What it is saying is when you are programming with threads, most of the time you dynamically create threads based on certain conditions that the programmer places in their code.  For example, finding prime numbers can be split up with threads but the creating and destruction of threads is made by the programmer.  You are completely correct, it is just saying what you are saying in a more descriptive and elaborate way.
Oh and for the thread management, sometimes if the developer sees that most of the time the user will need to create a large amount of threads, it is cheaper to spawn a pool of threads and use those.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 100 tasks to perform, all using independent--for the duration of the task--data.  Every thread you start costs quite a bit of overhead.  So if you have two cores, you only want to start two threads, because that's all that's going to run anyway.  Then you have to feed tasks to each of those threads to keep them both running.  If you have 100 cores, you'll launch 100 threads.  It's worth the overhead to get the job done 50 times faster.

So in old-fashioned programming, you have to do two jobs.  You have to find out how many cores you have, and you have to feed tasks to each of your threads so they keep running and don't waste cores.  (This becomes only one job if you have >= 100 cores.)

I believe Apple is offering take over these two awkward jobs for you.

If your jobs share data, that changes things.  With two threads running, one can block the other, and even on a 2-core machine it pays to have three or more threads running.  You are apt to find letting 100 threads loose at once makes sense because it improves the chances that at least two of them are not blocked.  It prevents one blocked task from holding up the rest of the tasks in its thread.  You pay a price in thread overhead, but get it back in high CPU usage.

So this feature is sometimes very useful and sometimes not.  It helps with *parallel* programming, but would hinder with non-parallel concurrency (multithreading).